# Is RAID1 volume usable while rebuilding RAID after disk failure?

Tags: disk-utility, raid

One disk of my 2-disk-RAID1-stack has failed and I'm about to replace it.

Is the volume usable—i.e. can I read & write just as I normally could—while Disk Utility is rebuilding the RAID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rebuilding happens in the background and the volume can be accessed normally.

I/O performance might be affected, but in my own experience it's more likely the rebuilding process that takes the performance-hit—i.e. rebuilding would be faster if the volume wasn't in use.

Comment: Also [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88355/1453) is still relevant as of El Capitan.